# QThread finished state

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

```
QThread * thread = new QThread();
qDebug() << "Finished: " << thread->isFinished();
```

Console is:

```
Finished: 0
```

The thread was **never** started, should not `isFinished()` returns **true** (1) instead of **false** (0) ?

NB: `isRunning` returns **0** and it is correct.

Comment: Looking at the source code the constructor sets finished to false. QThreadPrivate::QThreadPrivate(QThreadData *d)
    : QObjectPrivate(), running(false), finished(false),
      isInFinish(false), interruptionRequested(false),
      exited(false), returnCode(-1),
      stackSize(0), priority(QThread::InheritPriority), data(d) Here is a link to Qt 4.8 source (5.6 was the same at this) https://github.com/qt/qt/blob/4.8/src/corelib/thread/qthread.cpp

Comment: That is what I suspected. When the Thread start for first time, **isFinished () ** starts returning the correct values

Comment: ***starts returning the correct values*** I say its correct from the construction of the thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The finished state is there to indicate that before that `quit()` or `exit()` have been called. It is an alternative to receiving the `finished()` signal.

The `quit()` and `exit()` lead to `run()` (which is the only part of the thread that actually runs in a separate thread) returning to the thread that your `QThread` instance belongs to. After that a cleanup procedure is executed - events beside the designated deletion ones can no longer be processed.

The finished state is triggered and you can safely remove the instance of your `QThread`. `finished()` signal is emitted (in most cases connected to `deleteLater()` slots of the objects that reside in the separate thread) and `isFinished()` returns `true`.

Naturally if you haven't started the thread it cannot be finished because it never ran. :D Joke aside, it is perfectly safe to remove an instance of `QThread` that hasn't been started at all.

If you are more interested in this I suggest you look at the source code of `QThread` to see how the class is sturctured and its implementation works.

Comment: OK, I understand now what Finished state stands for. My guess was that Finished state is equivalent to Not Running, but it is different.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qthread.html#isFinished):

> **bool QThread::isFinished() const**
>
> Returns true if the thread is finished; otherwise returns false.
>
> See also isRunning().
>
> **bool QThread::isRunning() const**
>
> Returns true if the thread is running; otherwise returns false.
>
> See also isFinished().

For the thread to be finished it has to have been started beforehand.

Comment: From the first comment: finished(false) set to false in the constructor. I think it should be set to true?

Comment: ***I think it should be set to true***  This part is wrong / inconsistent with the documentation and the source code. It should not be set to true unless the thread actually started and finished.